# How does test automation work with regression testing?

Tags: testing, tdd

I am a little confused on the concept of test automation (using Selenium etc) when doing regression testing. If the system that is being tested is constantly under change, how does it affect the test cases? and is automation the best way to go in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Regression testing means you test to see if the system still behaves the way it should, in particular, if it still does everything it did correctly before any change.

Most users will complain when you break features in a software. So you don't get around regression testing before a release. That leaves the question as to how you do it.

You can manually test. Hire a bunch of monkeys, interns, testers, or whatever, and let them test. In order for them to find any regressions, they need to know what to test. So you need test scripts, which tell the tester what functionality to test: which button to click and what text to enter and then what result to expect. (This part rules out most monkeys, unfortunately.)

The alternative is automated testing: you still have a kind of test script, but at this time no manual tester works with the script, but a computer does instead.

Advantages of automated testing:

- It's usually faster than manual testing.
- You don't need to hire testers, interns, or monkeys.
- You don't need to worry about humans getting tired of the repetitive work, missing a step or getting tired of clicking through the same old program over and over.

Disadvantages of automated testing:

- Won't catch everything, in particular, some UI aspects may be hard to   automate: a person will notice overlapping texts or pink on neon green  text, but Selenium is happy if it can click it.
- First you need to write the tests, and then maintain them. If you just add features, maintenance is not soo bad, but if e.g., you restructure your user interface, you may have to adjust all tests ([Page Objects](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) may come in handy here). But then again you also have to re-write all manual tests in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Regression automation testing tools are the most widely used tools in the industry today. Let me help you with an example, considering your scenario which is 'Software undergoes continuous change'. Assume that we are following a Scrum based model in which the software will be developed across several sprints. Say each Sprint consists of 5 user stories/features. Sprint 1 is developed, tested and delivered.

Team moves to the next Sprint 2, which again has 5 big features. By the time, the development team hands over the features to the testing team, the testing team starts writing automated scripts for Sprint 1. Testing team runs the script say on a daily basis to check whether the features that are being developed in Sprint 2 do not break the previously working and tested features of Sprint 1. This is nothing but automating regression testing.

Of course, this is not as easy as it sounds. A lot of investment is needed for automated testing. Investment not only in terms of money but also time, training costs, hiring specialists etc.

I worked on project that consisted of approx. 25 sprints, hundreds of user stories and the project span across 2 years. With just 2 testers on the team, imagine the plight of the project had there been no Automation test suite.
Again, automation cannot entirely replace manual testing, but to quite-some extent. Automated tests can be functional as well visual regression ones. You can very well use Selenium to automate your functional tests and any other *visual regression tool to check CSS breaks.*

**NOTE**: Not every project needs to be automated. You have to consider the ***ROI (Return on Investment)*** when thinking about automating any project.

Comment: Scrum with team hands something over to the testing team? That doesn't sound agile.

Answer (score 0):

Regression testing is usually performed to verify code changes made into a system do not break existing code, introduce new bugs, or alter the system functionalities. As such, it should be performed every time you deploy a new functionality to your application, add a new module, alter system configurations, fix a defect, or perform changes to improve system performance.

Below is a simple regression test for some commonly used services in Python. This script helps catch errors that stem from changes made in a program’s source code.

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/python
import os, sys                            # get unix, python services 
from stat import ST_SIZE                  # or use os.path.getsize
from glob import glob                     # file name expansion
from os.path import exists                # file exists test
from time import time, ctime              # time functions

print 'RegTest start.' 
print 'user:', os.environ['USER']         # environment variables
print 'path:', os.getcwd(  )              # current directory
print 'time:', ctime(time(  )), '\n'
program = sys.argv[1]                     # two command-line args
testdir = sys.argv[2]

for test in glob(testdir + '/*.in'):      # for all matching input files
    if not exists('%s.out' % test):
        # no prior results
        os.system('%s < %s > %s.out 2>&1' % (program, test, test))
        print 'GENERATED:', test
    else: 
        # backup, run, compare
        os.rename(test + '.out', test + '.out.bkp')
        os.system('%s < %s > %s.out 2>&1' % (program, test, test))
        os.system('diff %s.out %s.out.bkp > %s.diffs' % ((test,)*3) )
        if os.stat(test + '.diffs')[ST_SIZE] == 0:
            print 'PASSED:', test 
            os.remove(test + '.diffs')
        else:
            print 'FAILED:', test, '(see %s.diffs)' % test

print 'RegTest done:', ctime(time(  ))
```

[Regression tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) like the one above are designed to cover both functional and non-functional aspects of an application. This ensures bugs are caught with every build, thereby enhancing the overall quality of the final product.  While regression tests are a vital part of the software QA process, performing these repetitive tests manually comes with a number of challenges. Manual tests can be tedious, time-consuming, and less accurate. Additionally, the number of test cases increases with every build, and so does the regression test suite grow.

An easy way of adressing the above challenges and maintaining a robust and cohesive set of regression test scripts is by automation. [Test automation](https://www.perfecto.io/blog/what-is-test-automation) increases the accuracy and widens the coverage of your regression tests as your test suite grows.

Worth a mention is that even with automation, your regression tests are only as good as your test scripts. For this reason, you must understand what events trigger the need to improve and modify the test scenarios. For every change pushed to your codebase, you should evaluate its impact and modify the scripts to ensure all affected code paths are verified.

I hope this answered your question.